# SQL Server stored procedure declare variable

Tags: sql-server, variables, set, declare

I have a stored procedure like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GETMONITORING] 
    @namabarang varchar (max)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @nWhere varchar(4000)
    SET @nwhere = ' where namabarang=''+@namabarang+'''

    SELECT 
        tanggalpermohonan, k.namaunitkerja, l.namajenislayanan, 
        namabarang, kodebarang, nup, r.namaruangan, p.lokasi, masalah
    FROM
        permohonan p
    JOIN
        UnitKerja k on k.idUnitKerja = p.idUnitKerja
    JOIN
        JenisLayanan l on l.idJenisLayanan = p.JenisLayananID
    JOIN
        MasterRuangan r on r.KodeRuang = p.KodeRuang

    PRINT @nwhere
end
```

I exec that stored procedure using 'ac' as parameter for `@namabarang` and it result all rows. If I run in query like this

```
select 
    tanggalpermohonan, k.namaunitkerja, l.namajenislayanan, 
    namabarang, kodebarang, nup, r.namaruangan, p.lokasi, masalah
from
    permohonan p
join 
    UnitKerja k on k.idUnitKerja = p.idUnitKerja
join 
    JenisLayanan l on l.idJenisLayanan = p.JenisLayananID
join 
    MasterRuangan r on r.KodeRuang = p.KodeRuang
where 
    namabarang = 'ac'
```

that query only result 1 row as I want. What should I do if I want that stored procedure with `AC` as `@parameter` to only return one row ?

Thank you

Comment: you are not using @nwhere variable anywhere in SP.

Comment: that is just example. My problem is I want to combine multiple variables. for example 
set @a= 'select * '
set @b= 'from table'

how to join those variable?
so  all that I want is like @a+@b

Answer (score 1):

Modify your procedure as below sample for equal search

```
alter procedure GetData(@parmeter varchar(5))
as 
begin

declare @basequery varchar(max);
declare @where varchar(max);
declare @final varchar(max);

set @basequery='select * from doctest '
set @where='where docId = '+@parmeter

set @final=@basequery+@where
execute(@final)

end
```

Comment: Don't do this. This sort of pattern is just asking for SQL Injection attacks

Comment: I've tried. But local variable cant contain =(equal). How I can input =(equal) into local variable ?

Answer (score 0):

Print is not going to be part of your query, it will literally just print to the messages tab of SSMS or your query tool. It is useful for status updates, not for generating a query.

Don't use varchar(max) for the parameter type. Make it the same is the actual data type of the namabarang field. If you want to be able to put multiple values into the parameter, then this won't work.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GETMONITORING] 
@namabarang varchar (max)

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT 
    tanggalpermohonan, k.namaunitkerja, l.namajenislayanan, 
    namabarang, kodebarang, nup, r.namaruangan, p.lokasi, masalah
FROM
    permohonan p
JOIN
    UnitKerja k on k.idUnitKerja = p.idUnitKerja
JOIN
    JenisLayanan l on l.idJenisLayanan = p.JenisLayananID
JOIN
    MasterRuangan r on r.KodeRuang = p.KodeRuang
WHERE namabarang = @namabarang
```

end

Don't do this:

```
exec GETMONITORING 'ac'
```

Be specific about the schema, and always use named parameters because it will help you when there are multiple parameters, and when the code changes,

Do this:

```
exec dbo.GETMONITORING @namabarang = 'ac'
```

Comment: thank you. but for some reason I cant use 'namabarang = @namabarang'

I need declare and set

Comment: What do you mean you can't use that? Do you have some error, or you have another reason?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GETMONITORING] 
@namabarang varchar (max) 
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @nWhere NVARCHAR(4000) = ' where namabarang = '''+@namabarang+'''';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
SELECT 
    tanggalpermohonan, k.namaunitkerja, l.namajenislayanan, 
    namabarang, kodebarang, nup, r.namaruangan, p.lokasi, masalah
FROM
    permohonan p
JOIN
    UnitKerja k on k.idUnitKerja = p.idUnitKerja
JOIN
    JenisLayanan l on l.idJenisLayanan = p.JenisLayananID
JOIN
    MasterRuangan r on r.KodeRuang = p.KodeRuang ' + @nWhere;

exec sp_executesql @sql
END
```

And then:

```
exec dbo.GETMONITORING @namabarang = 'ac'
```